# Why does the concat method not match up columns in multiple files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to merge three files together, into one file.  Here are the field names in File1.

```
"IDRSSD"    RIAD4097    RIAD4235    RIAD4239    RIAD4341    RIAD4797    RIAD4843    RIAD4844    RIAD4845    RIAD4846    RIADB523    RIADB524    RIADB525    
    NON INT INCM OF INTL BUSINESS   PROV FOR LOAN LOSS, INTL BUSINESS   NON-INT EXPENSE, INTL BUSINESS  NET INCM ATTRIB TO INTL BUSINESS    INCOME TAX ATTRIB TO INTL BUSINESS  NET NON-INT INC(EXP) ATTRIB TO INT O    EST PRETAX INC ATTRIG TO INT OPR    ADJ TO PRETAX INC FOR INTERNAL ALLOC    EST PRETAX INC ATTRIB TO INT OPR AFT    GROSS INTEREST INCOME (INTERNL OPER)    GROSS INTEREST EXPENSE (INTERNL OPER    NET INTEREST INCOME (INTERNATL OPER)
```

Here are the field names in File2.

```
"IDRSSD"    RIADC899    RIADC900    RIADC902    RIADC903    RIADC904    RIADC905    RIADC907    RIADC908    RIADC909    RIADC911    RIADC913    RIADC914    RIADGW64    RIADJA28    RIADKW02    
    TOTAL INTEREST INCOME IN FOREIGN OFF    TOT INTEREST EXPENSE IN FOREIGN OFFI    NONINT INCOME FRGN OFFICS:TRADNG REV    NONINT INC FRG OFFCS:INVMT BKG,ADVRY    NONINT INC FRG OFFCS:NT SECURIZATION    NONINT INC FRGN OFFICS:OTHER NONINTE    TOTAL NONINT EXPENSE IN FOREIGN OFFI    ADJMTS TO PRETAX INC FOREIGN OFFICES    APPLICABLE INCOME TAXES NET INC ATTRIBUTABLE TO FRGN OFFICES    ELIMINATIONS ARISING FRM CONSOLIDATN    CONSOLIDTD NET INC ATTRIBTLE FRGN OF    DISCONTINUED OPERATIONS, NET OF APPL    'Realized gains/losses on held-to-ma    Provision for loan and lease losses
```

Here are the filed names in File3.

```
"IDRSSD"    RIADC899    RIADC900    RIADC902    RIADC903    RIADC904    RIADC905    RIADC907    RIADC908    RIADC909    RIADC911    RIADC913    RIADC914    RIADGW64    RIADJA28    RIADKW02    
    TOTAL INTEREST INCOME IN FOREIGN OFF    TOT INTEREST EXPENSE IN FOREIGN OFFI    NONINT INCOME FRGN OFFICS:TRADNG REV    NONINT INC FRG OFFCS:INVMT BKG,ADVRY    NONINT INC FRG OFFCS:NT SECURIZATION    NONINT INC FRGN OFFICS:OTHER NONINTE    TOTAL NONINT EXPENSE IN FOREIGN OFFI    ADJMTS TO PRETAX INC FOREIGN OFFICES    APPLICABLE INCOME TAXES NET INC ATTRIBUTABLE TO FRGN OFFICES    ELIMINATIONS ARISING FRM CONSOLIDATN    CONSOLIDTD NET INC ATTRIBTLE FRGN OF    DISCONTINUED OPERATIONS, NET OF APPL    'Realized gains/losses on held-to-ma    Provision for loan and lease losses
```

Now, I run this code.

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd

path = "C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\schemas\\"

all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))

all_df = []
for f in all_files: 
   df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='\t') 
   df['file'] = os.path.basename(f)
   all_df.append(df) 

df_append = pd.concat(all_df, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
df_append.to_csv("C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\merged.csv")
```

Now, when I filter Column O, I see this.

```
RIADC899
TOTAL INTEREST INCOME IN FOREIGN OFF
TOTAL INTEREST INCOME IN FOREIGN OFF
```

Here are three screen shots of the data when it is imported into Excel.

Pic1:
[image]

Pic2:
[image]

Pic3:
[image]

Shouldn't the field names line up?  To see 'TOTAL INTEREST INCOME IN FOREIGN OFF' 2x totally makes sense, but why would the field named 'RIADC899' be in the same column?  What is wrong here?

Comment: Not ideal that you are using tab-separated fields. Hard to consume in this forum.

Comment: most likely the use of concat when you have different column names in each df you are combining. maybe look into merge? but as jarmod mentioned, if you post your file data as json, or lists, it can be consumed easier.

Comment: I just updated my original post. Sorry, but I always try to keep it very, very simple. Maybe I over-simplify the issue sometimes.

Comment: [You](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1347778) have the most answers, and also the highest zero-score answer ratio on the site! You will get your rep in the heaven. Merry xmas!